# Implementing a storyboard project into a XIB based project

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xib, ios6.1

So I have been working on a project in the most recent version of Xcode, I am NOT using storyboard, just standard nibs. However I found excellent source code for an RSS reader I would like to add into my project. I added the entire source code into my project as well as the .storyboard file. I have a tab bar application and would like to have one of the tabs the lead to the storyboards RootViewController (the main page of the RSS Reader). Could anyone help me with this. IT would be extremely appreciated!! This is the source code that I used if you need it: https://github.com/julien-sarazin/iReader-RSS

Thanks!!

Comment: Wow just found the answer, its actually quite easy, simply watch the WWDC keynote on implementing storyboard here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Comment: Good job answering your own question. You should post the above comment as an answer and accept it. That way this question will not be in the unanswered list. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow just found the answer, its actually quite easy, simply watch the WWDC keynote on implementing storyboard here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/